# mathematical adjustment (IRR)

Tags: quadratics

Is here anybody who can help me with mathematical adjustment between equation 8 and 9 in the picture?

[image]

Ignore the text between equations

Comment: Welcome to maths SE. Could you edit your post to include the equation instead of a picture? [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) will help you typeset your equation. Also, could you include your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an instance of *completing the square*.

Note that $$(x-\frac{CF_1}{2CF_2})^2 = x^2 - \frac{CF_1}{CF_2}x + \frac{CF_1^2}{4CF_2^2}$$

Recognize that the right hand side of this equation is just the right hand side of $(8)$ + $\frac{CF_1^2}{4CF_2^2}$.

Thus if you add $\frac{CF_1^2}{4CF_2^2}$ to both sides of the equation in $(8)$, you get that $$\frac{y - CF_0}{CF_2} + \frac{CF_1^2}{4CF_2^2} = (x-\frac{CF_1}{2CF_2})^2$$ which gets you to $(9)$ after multiplying by $CF_2$.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @MiroslavHolub You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they used the quadratic formula...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1295720)

Comment: ^^ I think, as is, this is more appropriate as a comment.  To qualify as an answer I think you should elaborate a little bit.... show a couple steps?

Comment: Did the OP show steps?

Comment: The OP was essentially asking how to get the canonical parabolic form from a quadratic equation.  There's an intermediate step that the text in the image didn't spell out.  Seemed to me like the OP just needed it to be made explicit.